# How to get a virtual machine onto the LAN

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, minecraft, virt-manager

I've got Manjaro(Arch) at 192.168.0.2 running minecraft open to LAN connections and an excited 7 year old wanting to play with his dad.  My old as dirt laptop finally died and I've replaced it with a PureOS laptop because I believe in free software. But that belief crumples when it comes to playing with my kid (and he thinks the textures in MineTest look off. Tsk).

Having a prior horrific experience with getting minecraft to run with free drivers, I'm running ubuntu with the jre in a virtual box (gnome boxes).   Minecraft runs slow, and there's a silly workaround with the mouse, but whatever, it's fine.

But I can't get the virtual ubuntu box to ping the arch box on the LAN.   I thought this part would be easy. Looking around, I believe I need a bridged network interface.

I can run `virsh edit Ubuntu` and set the network interface to bridge and use the virbr0 interface, ala [this guys advice](http://xkahn.zoned.net/blog/2013/11/26/networking-and-gnome-boxes/). But that just causes the VM to not launch.  Maybe "bridging isn't set up".   I'm pretty sure I can do the same thing via `virt-manager` and setting the network source from "Usermode" to "specify shared device name" an putting in "virbr0" for the bridge name. Same results.

...how do I set up a gnome boxes VM to use a bridged network interface? and/or how do I set up a bridged network interface?

I'm trying to use virt-manager to do that. There's the whole user-session vs system-session thing I'm not clear on. It failed to launch running it with sudo, although it asks for permissions on startup otherwise.

(Adding the specific source of that error: Virt-manager (with the user session selected, which has the VM running) -> Edit -> Connection Details -> Add Network.  The gui wizard has a bunch of options I'm leaving as default. If there's a command-line means of doing this with better error reporting, I'm all ears.)

I keep getting `libvirt.libvirtError: error creating bridge interface virbr1: Operation not permitted` trying to make a virtual network that isn't NAT forwarded like virbr0 in the system-session.

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm also open to any simpler solution here. Really, I feel like I'm letting down my kid. Feels bad.

Comment: How can we tell you what is wrong if you haven’t provided the commands you are running? An error without cause is pretty useless.

Comment: thanks, and duly noted. I've added the steps I'm taking to throw the error in virt-manager.

Comment: Start by reading: [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)